# Which type of data structures can be implemented by a linked list?

Tags: data-structures

I know for sure that stacks and queues can be implemented using a linked list but I was having my doubts if trees could also be implemented.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about a singly linked list, then it is not possible since we cannot have information about children with only a single pointer.

A combination of linked-list with map or array can be used to create different types of data structure namely LRU, HashMap(single chain collision), B+Tree, etc